# cakephp version 3 file structure for multiple apps

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am a relatively new user of Cakephp and have been using Version 2 for just a few months.

I am having trouble finding info on folder structure for multiple apps with Cakephp 3. My current structure:

```
app_myapp1 (app files)
app_myapp2 (app files)
cake_core (core files)

public_html 
-> myapp1 (webroot files)
-> myapp2 (webroot files)
```

How do I set up the version 3 folders in order to have multiple apps with the same core files?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your method is no longer supported

> CakePHP should be installed with Composer Since CakePHP can no longer
>   easily be installed via PEAR, or in a shared directory, those options
>   are no longer supported. Instead you should use Composer to install
>   CakePHP into your application.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html